# Is it possible to reuse water extracted from the PACKs Water extractors?

Tags: aircraft-systems, pack

During the Process inside of the Air Generation Unit (AGU) there is a water extractor behind the condenser separating the water from the air which will flow to the Re-Heater.

Is it posible to filter this water and re-use it for lavatory flush or hand wash water?

Since Humidity at FL300 is around 3%, is there even sufficient water being extracted to refill the tanks?

Comment: If you did reclaim it, I'm sure it would be fine to use as non-potable (term for water you don't drink). Whether or not it is worth the extra weight, cost, and maintenance is another matter though that I'm guessing the answer is  "not worth it" when you can just take a small tank of water with you.

Answer (score 8):

Water comes from condensing water vapor present in the cabin, itself coming from human breathing and perspiration, and, for a small part, from atmosphere.

The question mentions an *air generation unit* which is an Airbus terminology, so let's go into the A380 air system:

[image]
<sup>A380 Engineering training, [source](https://fr.scribd.com/document/35240967/003-CHAP-21-Air-Conditioning) (page 101)</sup>

The two green labels are my addition to show the extractor and a spray nozzle. Water separated by a cyclone in the extractor is sprayed into ram air just after the ram air inlet and before entering the heat exchangers of the air-cycle machines. Spraying water droplets creates evaporation, hence a temperature drop in the exchanger receiving fluid, increasing air exchanger capacity.

Bleed air from the engines/atmosphere is colder and dryer at high altitude. Air exchangers work better, but cabin atmosphere may be dry for human well being. A fraction of condensed water can be returned to conditioned air going to the cabin. This is done automatically by the air-conditioning system.

To answer your question: Water is already fully reused.