# Is it a bad idea to brush your teeth with water from an airliner sink faucet?

Tags: airlines

Is it a bad idea to brush your teeth with water from an airliner sink faucet?  Does some sort of health risk from said water outweigh the risk of poor dental hygiene?

Comment: this question is informed by something I heard on the radio today.

Comment: [This might be related info](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/33713/what-would-non-potable-water-be-used-for-on-an-airliner)

Comment: There is often a queue for the lavatory, so think about other passengers before taking it potentially for much longer than a typical visit requires.

Comment: It belongs to travel.se

Comment: The question this is marked as a duplicate of seems barely related, let alone a duplicate.

Comment: There might not be a generally valid answer, it depends on the airline and the departure airport. Here's a [newspaper article in German](https://www.abendblatt.de/reise/article206697357/Wasserqualitaet-auf-Flugzeug-Klo-zum-Zaehneputzen-geeignet.html) ([translated](https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&u=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.abendblatt.de%2Freise%2Farticle206697357%2FWasserqualitaet-auf-Flugzeug-Klo-zum-Zaehneputzen-geeignet.html)).